# What does "request for member in something not a structure or union" mean?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int busqueda_indexada(int a[], int n, int x) {
    int elementos[3]; int indice[3];
    int g; int i;
    int set=0; int ind=0;
    
    for (i=0; i<n-1; i+=3) {
        elementos[ind].nombre=a[i]);
        elementos[ind].indice = i;
        i+=3;
        ind++;
    }

    if (x<elementos[0].boleto) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        for (i=1; i<g-1; i++)
            if (x<elementos[i].elem) {
                int ini = elementos[i-1].indice;
                int fin = elementos[i].indice;
                set = 1;
                break;
            }
    }
    
    if (set==0) {
        int ini = elementos[G-1].indice;
        int fin = n-1;
    }   
}

struct elementos {
    int indice;
    char nombre[100];
    int boleto;
} elementos a[3];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct elementos a[3] = {"marco", 1, "sin asignar", 2, "pedro", 3};
    printf("%s y %d", a[2].nombre, a[2].boleto);
    busqueda_indexada(a, n, x)
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know how the indexed search can read my structure. I tried everything and always shows

> [Error] request for member '' in something not a structure or union

every time I tried to call a structure. Maybe I defined bad my struct or I call it in the wrong way?

Comment: If `struct elementos` contains an int, a string (char array), and another int, then `struct elementos a[3] = {"marco", 1, "sin asignar", 2, "pedro", 3};` is a very odd initializer to use. Where's `indice` for each one?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], your code does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

With `elementos[ind].nombre` You try to access a field on `elementos[ind]`, but that itself is a int. `.something` in only allowed, if `elementos[ind]` would eithet be a struct or an union.

Answer (score 0):

You use `elementos` for two different things:

- In `busqueda_indexada()` for a local array of `int`;
- Outside any function for a structure.

The error (among a lot more) is given the first time for `elementos[ind].nombre`. This is the `ind`th element of the local array, an `int`, which is clearly no structure.

Please raise the warning level of your compiler to the maximum and correct your code until all errors and warnings are gone.

Use descriptive names for structures and variables.